# update collection by downloading only the changes

Tags: meteor

in our application we use some really big collections (>250K documents). The application has to be used offline, hence the need to store the entire collection on the client.

the two packages [grounddb](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/Meteor-GroundDB) and [offline-data](https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data) both synchronize the whole collection as soon as the network is present.

In the spirit of saving bandwidth and providing the user with a decent performance, I am looking for a way to avoid downloading the entire collection every time the application connects to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use offline-data you could make publish that accepts a offset and a max record argument. Then when the status of the subscription is loaded add another one with the next offset.

Edit:
Add a timestamp argument to the publish then subscribe with given timestamp. only return the items with a timestamp greater than the given timestamp.

Comment: this will still download the entire collection for every session. I would prefer to store the collection offline and then only download the deltas the next time I connect